# Ad-hoc content access restriction

Tags: 7, users

is there a way to restrict content access to a specific subset of users upon node creation without having to create a specific user role and/or organic group?

For instance having a list of users to refer to upon node creation, and allowing ONLY them to view/visit/edit the node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, the [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module does exactly that. You specify a list of user and grant them actions upon the node. Awesome.

Comment: as mentioned below* now :P

Answer (score 1):

as far as I am concerned, you can use these modules to achieve what you want :)

[Content Access module](http://drupal.org/project/content_access)

[Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench)

Comment: Thanks a lot Vic, but I achieved the functionality already using http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference . I'll answer my own question once the timer expires :)